# svg path not drawing correctly

Tags: html, svg, path, draw

I'm tring to draw a simple path about a radio signal. On y only 0 or 1 could be provided and on x is the delay in nanoseconds.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>GPIO TEST</title>
  <style>
   html, body
   {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <svg width="100%" height="50%" style="border:1px solid #000;" viewBox="0 -0.2 384071041 1.2" version="1.1" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="M 0 0 v 1 h 26379904 v 1 h 41916258 v 1 h 58997548 v 1 h 73918928 v 0 h 88221334 v 1 h 99886849 v 0 h 116664152 v 1 h 132164508 v 1 h 147551869 v 0 h 164463167 v 0 h 179546540 v 0 h 192406006 v 0 h 206892404 v 1 h 220718829 v 0 h 236095190 v 1 h 251343557 v 0 h 266534925 v 1 h 282160276 v 0 h 293355811 v 0 h 306647258 v 1 h 322362605 v 1 h 336254028 v 1 h 352724344 v 1 h 369630641 v 0 h 384071041" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="0.001"></path>
  </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```

I've tried to change the stroke-width in any possible number, but the result is inconsistent.

The result should be something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've just noticed that i should had used the 'H' for horizontal lines and the 'V' for verticals because i got only absolute coordinates and not dx ( delta X ) and dy ( delta Y ).

As MDN say: [H x (or h dx
V y (or v dy)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)